# What is the mount on Vivitar lens with MIR printed on mount side?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, adapter, vivitar, equipment-identification

Got a Vivitar 28mm F2.8 manual-focus lens with MIR printed on the mount side. I want to use it with my Sony E-mount camera. I got a Minolta MD adapter to E-mount, but it didn't work. This is my first time trying to adapt a vintage lens to a digital camera.

Lens markings:

- AUTO Vivitar Wide-Angle 28 mm 1:2.8 No. 3716210, Made in Japan
- MIR (on mount side)

[image: composite of lens photos]

Comment: Vivitar made lenses in a wide variety of mounts. You need to show us the other end of the lens or we cant help you very much.

Comment: i added some more picture. hope it helps. And thank you so much for replying and helping a beginner. Really appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I would venture to say that it's a Miranda Bayonet Mount.

I use visual references and measurements to positively determine a mount. I would advise that you do the same before investing in another adapter. But your lens does have MIR imprinted which is a good clue. Confirm what you have with these resources:

- http://members.tripod.com/rick_oleson/index-99.html
- http://wycameras.com/35mm-slr-lens-mount-identification-guide/
- http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Lens_mounts

And if the adapter is so obscure that it costs a lot. You may want to consider finding the same cheap Vivitar lens online that has a more common mount with inexpensive adapters.

Good luck!

Comment: Fotodiox sells a Miranda lens to Sony E mount adapter for about $40.

Answer (score 3):

This is either a Vivitar T4 or TX series lens. T4 and TX lenses are interesting because they were designed to be mount-agnostic; that is, they have interchangeable mount adapters, so you could move your lens to bodies with different mounts, just by getting the appropriate Vivitar T4/TX adapter.

As Gabe Krause's answer indicates, *this particular* lens has the Miranda mount adapter on it. You can get a Miranda lens to Sony E mount adapter pretty inexpensively.

Alternately, especially if you already have adapters to mount other lenses to your Sony E mount body, search sites such as eBay for Vivitar T4 (or TX) mount to (whatever adapter you already have). You can "convert" your Vivitar lens to that mount, so it will use the 3rd party Sony E mount adapter you have, meaning you will need to carry one less adapter with you.